# Where's environment variables SHELL and BASH defined in OS X?

Tags: bash, zsh

When I execute `set` in my bash terminal, among many other things I see this and I can't figure out where these are defined:

```
BASH=/usr/local/bin/zsh
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/zsh
```

Since I've uninstalled zsh I wish to make sure applications are not reading these environment variables and attempt to use zsh. I've noticed that Sublime Text 3 generates errors because it reads the `SHELL` environment variable.

I've checked `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` but there's no definitions in them where these environment variables are defined.

When checking Terminal.app's settings, it's set to use `/bin/bash`.

Where are these environment variables defined?

Comment: Check http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html

Comment: `SHELL` is set by [*login* **(1)**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277949/19240).  `BASH` is set by [Bash itself](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Bash-Variables).

Comment: @123 No, that's a red herring here.

Comment: @tripleee Could still be set in any of those files after login.

Comment: The shell's startup files are not involved in setting either of the variables here.  If they were to override the reasonable default values, that could be a serious problem, so I would regard the objection as purely theoretical.

Comment: @tripleee okay :)

Answer (score 1):

`SHELL` (just as `HOME`, `USER`, `LOGNAME`) is set from the values for login shell (home directory and user name) in the user database.

On OSX you can read out the value for your login shell from the user database with

```
dscl localhost -read Local/Default/Users/$USER UserShell
```

On most other Unix-like operating systems you can retrieve your login data with

```
getent passwd $USER
```

where the last (colon-separated) field usually denotes the login shell.

In order to change `SHELL`, you need to change your login shell. This can be achieved with the `chsh` utility. For example, if you want to set it to `bash`, you can do so with

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

The change will take effect at the next login (it is not sufficient to close and re-open the terminal window).
Note, that the full path to the shell needs to be given and the path has to be listed in `/etc/shells`.

---

`BASH` is set by bash itself and should expand to the absolute path used to run the current instance of `bash`.

The fact that it expands to `/usr/local/bin/zsh` in your case, leads me to suspect that it is a linked or copied version of `/bin/bash`. I would suggest to remove that link/file *after* changing the login shell an confirming that the change took effect.